# How to quantify bias and variance given train data samples

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

I have a model that I train using polynomial and radial basis functions, I split the data into train set and test set and I take a lot of samples from the train set. Now I'm at a loss for the next step, I know bias is the loss of the sample with the least loss. Do I calculate this on train data or test data? Is the variance just the variance of the losses on the test set?

Comment: You seem to have a confusion about basic statistical terms. Stack overflow is more focused on coding questions, have a look at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead. And look for a good tutorial about bias/variance trade-off, there should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of this tradeoff is to ***find the right amount of complexity for the decision boundary***.

**High complexity:** (Could) Memorizes the past and (may) not generalize for the future (High variance problem)

**Low complexity:** (Could) not learn enough from the past because of very simple decision boundary and again (may) fail to have a good prediction as well (high bias problem)

This could be simply shown with a figure like the following,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I'm looking for a way to give a number to the bias and one to the variance to show which models are good and which are bad with numbers.